# pandas count regex matches and groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking for a way to extract the most frequent hashtags (per user and in total) from a DataFrame containing user names and twitter texts. The twitter texts can contain hashtags.

```
           username tweet_id    created_at  text    in_reply_to_tweet_id    in_reply_to_user    retweet_count   favorite_count
    0   mmitchell_ai    1506357982061158401 2022-03-22 19:51:44+00:00   What does it mean to "sanction" Google? What a...   NaN NaN 1   12
    1   mmitchell_ai    1506357632793149441 2022-03-22 19:50:21+00:00   RT @SanhEstPasMoi: @ClementDelangue @aurelieng...   NaN NaN 1   0
```

See example data above.

I am able to get the overal occurence of each hashtag as follows

```
import re

df.text.str.extractall(r'(\#\w+)')[0].value_counts()
```

but I am not able to group the result by user name.

Answer (score 0):

You are close. You missed to join the result to your original dataframe:

```
hashtags = df['text'].str.extractall(r'(?P<hashtag>\#\w+)').droplevel(1)
out = df[['username']].join(hashtags).value_counts()
print(out)

# Output
username      hashtag  
mmitchell_ai  #hashtag2    2
              #hashtag1    1
              #hashtag3    1
dtype: int64
```

Input data:

```
>>> df
       username                                     text
0  mmitchell_ai  blah blah #hashtag1 blah #hashtag2 blah
1  mmitchell_ai       blah #hashtag3 blah blah #hashtag2
```